# Linear regression in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I started learning maching learning on Python using Pandas and Sklearn.
I tried to use the `LinearRegression().fit` method :

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
house_data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\yassine\Desktop\ml\OC-tp-ML\house_data.csv")
y = house_data[["price"]] 
x = house_data[["surface","arrondissement"]] 
X = house_data.iloc[:, 1:3].values  
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split (x, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=1) 
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

When I run the code, I have this message :

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Can You help me please.

Comment: The error tells you the problem, you have `NaN` values, `infinite` values, or extremely large values that scikit can't handle. Check for `NaN` rows in your data and try to remove them

Comment: house_data.info(), check the null value

Comment: I got this :house_data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 827 entries, 0 to 826
Data columns (total 3 columns):
price             827 non-null int64
surface           822 non-null float64
arrondissement    822 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(1)
memory usage: 19.5 KB

Comment: Please do not use the comments space for posting code & results - edit & update your post instead

Answer (score 4):

Machine learning models may require you to impute the data as part of your data cleaning process. Linear regression cares a lot about the yhat, so I usually start with imputing the mean. If you aren't comfortable imputing the missing data, you can drop the observations that contain NaN (provided you only have a small proportion of NaN observations.)

Imputing the mean can look like this:

```
df = df.fillna(df.mean())
```

Imputing to zero can look like this:

```
df = df.fillna(0)
```

Imputing to a custom result can look like:

```
df = df.fillna(my_func(args))
```

Dropping altogether can look like:

```
df = df.dropna()
```

Prepping so that `inf` may be caught by these methods ahead of time can look like:

```
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
```